# Could I change the schema of GeoWebCache "File" BlobStore provider to match the S3 one?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Using the "File" BlobStore in a GeoWebCache (integrated in GeoServer), results in files being stored this way (example for zoom level 0)

`[...]/EPSG_900913_00/0_0/00_00.png`

Using the "S3" BlobStore provider, stores the files like this:

`[...]/EPSG:900913/png/default/0/0/0.png`

Can I configure the "File" provider in any way to store the files with the TMS schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

- Go into the blostores menu
- Create a new file blobstore
- Choose the TMS layout
- Save
- Choose that blobstore for your tiles

But... make sure your filesystem can handle the TMS layout... as zoom levels go up, the number of tiles stored in a single directory can go beyond the millions.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I've missed that. I made a separate partition using btrfs, after being bitten by the filesystem limitation, should be ok now.